# Page not found, broken link?

Tags: support, specific-question, 404-not-found

I was on SO with my Android and I got "Page not fond" by clicking the question title "[What Are The Best Practices With using Different Loops in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727272/what-are-the-best-practices-with-using-different-loops-in-php)" from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because <s>you</s> OP deleted it. <s>I have flagged that question to undelete by moderator.</s>,

<sub>Asked again to cancel about undelete, sorry my mistake without looking the names carefully.</sub>

Comment: It was deleted, but by the question owner, not him

Comment: ahhhhhh, I should have checked the name carefully

Comment: Sorry, I'm new, i can't get the point.

Comment: @Cesar, question owner deleted the question, thats why.

Comment: why it's was still in the list ? it's a kind of cache system ?

Comment: Yeah, thats a cache