# Question link broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, hyperlinks, broken-link

I've tried pressing on the question link - and I got only a search result page with no results.

I've tried refreshing the list of questions (general new questions) but still the question is there and the link is broken.

[This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875240/longest-realistic-method-name)

Comment: It's been deleted and hence is only visible to 10K+ users and moderators

Comment: related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/page-not-found-broken-link/48081#48081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link isn't broken: the question was recently deleted. The list of questions doesn't update immediately on the deletion of the question, so it can remain around for some time.

Question's still around for people with at least 10k reputation or moderator status.

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't clicking the link give me that information?

Comment: The error page states "Occasionally questions or answers may be removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etcetera.", implying that the question was removed. As to why SO uses an error message to purport an illusion that the content is fully gone... well, I guess it's to keep the deleted-content-viewing capability more of a surprise.